# Javascript float issue with decimals ending on 00

Tags: javascript, math

I have a string with numbers in, and I extract the numbers from the string, and then convert the numbers to a float with a fixed decimal point to 2.

If I use the following: 
I was using the following texts on this:

- 28 dollars and 29 cents
- 7 dollars

I also tried playing around with numbers like 7.00, 2.28, 228 and 700 to see different results. In my database the numbers are stored as 7.00 or 2.28, and then converted to a string like above. But now I want to get those numbers again from the string to be 7.00 and 2.28, but 7.00 gets returned as 0.07.

```
function total() {
    let cartP = document.querySelectorAll('.cart-price-button');
    let totalP = document.querySelector('.cart-total');
    let price = 0;
    let total = 0;

    for(let i = 0; i < cartP.length; i++) {
        price = cartP[i].textContent.replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''); //extracts the numbers from string
        total += parseFloat(price/100); //converts to float number


       console.log(total); //returns integer of 2.28 or 0.07 (how can I get it to be 7.00)

    }

    console.log((total.toFixed(2))); //returns number string
}
```

I know why it is happening, but I think I am starting to over think this which is causing me to run into a wall.

Comment: Could you at least explain what you're trying to do with that regular expression? If the regular expression is confusing you, or not working how you think it should, then **don't use a regular expression**.

Comment: Its not the regular expression. I get that and it works. I was getting the numbers out of a string eg '31 dollars and 23 cents' to give me 3123 as per the example and then I would convert it to a float eg 31.23. My issue was that if it is just eg '7 dollars' that it would not return 7.00 but either 7 or 0.07 with the methods I was trying.

Answer (score 0):

You need to multiply it with 100 and divide it 100. It will give you a proper result.

```js
var cartP = ["7 dollers", "2 doller 28 cents", "700 dollers"];
var total = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < cartP.length; i++) {
  price = cartP[i].replace(/[^\d.-]/g, ''); //extracts the numbers from string
  if (cartP[i].includes("cents")) {
total += parseFloat(price / 100); //converts to float number
  } else {
total += parseFloat(price); //converts to float number 
  }
  console.log(total); //returns integer of 2.28 or 0.07 (how can I get it to be 7.00)

}
```

Comment: The text is not in an array, the buttons are. My text comprise of 7 dollars, or 2 dollar 28 cents. I get 2.28 cents fine, but I don't get 7.00. When I tried your solution I get 228 and 7. I want 7.00. The 2.28 is fine.

Comment: @Horcrux, I have updated my answer, Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Try following.

```
function total() {
    let cartP = document.querySelectorAll('.cart-price-button');
    let totalP = document.querySelector('.cart-total');
    let price = 0;
    let total = 0;

    for(let i = 0; i < cartP.length; i++) {

        let matches = cartP[i].textContent.match(/\d+/g);
        if (matches[1] === null) {
              price = matches[0];
        }
        else {
              price = matches[0] +"." + matches[1];
        }
        total += parseFloat(price); //converts to float number
        console.log(total); //returns integer of 2.28 or 0.07 (how can I get it to be 7.00)
    }
    console.log((total.toFixed(2))); //returns number string
}
```